# grep two string as variable to use in a script

Tags: linux

Could you pls help me how can i grep and use the strings mentioned below as variable at the 3rd line in the file.txt involved.

file.txt

```
line1:  some words with 123@domain.com
line2:  some words 
line3:  path = /aaa/bbb/domain.com/user@domain.com/ccc/123@test.com/
```

So need to grep "user@domain.com" and "123@test"  at line3 to use as variables in a script like ;

```
#!/bin/bash
var1 = some_code result as "user@domain.com"
var2 = some_code result as "123@test"
run_a_command  $var1  $var2
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format of the file is same as you have shown then you could do:

```
arr=($(awk -F'/' '/path/{print $5,$7}' file)) # Extract the desired 2 fields

arr[1]=${arr[1]%\.com} # Remove the suffix ".com"

run_a_command ${a[0]} ${a[1]}
```

Depending on the file content, you may also want to adjust the `awk` part to extract. You can also check if the one or both array elements are empty if that could be a possibility. If it's always third line, then you can do using `NR==3` check in the awk pattern matching part: `arr=($(awk -F'/' 'NR==3 && /path/{print $5,$7}' file))`.

If the input file has more complex format (E.g. what if multiple such lines are there in the input file etc), then you should update the question as any solution depends on that.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
grep -o -E '\/[^\/]+@[^\/\.]+' INFILE | sed "s/\///g"
```

Maybe the following is what you are looking for?

```
grep -o -E '\/[^\/]+@[^\/]+(\/|$)' INFILE | sed "s/\///g"
```

Comment: that's fine but i need strings to get separately.